# Rmd vs Md for blogdown and blogposts

Tags: markdown, rendering, r-markdown, blogs, blogdown

Is it generally better to use Rmd or Md for blogposts in hugo with blogdown? I often see many blog posts written in MD files based on what I see from GitHub repositories, but I also saw a blogpost on the bookdown website suggesting that it's better to go with rmd, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: When feeling confused, please take some time to read the documentation: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html

Comment: I was about to draft an answer but the docs @YihuiXie linked are basically the more authoritative version of what I'd have written. Long story short: .md fast and simple but no R code, .Rmd complexer and with R code but maybe compatibility issues depending on themes and stuff. Depends on the use case.